# Hi, I'm trying to connect two nodes from different classes and for some reason it's giving me this error ->neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code:

Tags: python, merge, neo4j, match, nodes

'''
This is the function that connects 2 nodes from different classes, the nodes exist
'''

def Lives_inRelationship(name,num):

```
session = graphdb.session()

session.run("MATCH (" + name + ":person {name:'" + name + "'}), ("+num+":Apartment {number:'" + num + "'})"

            "MERGE (" + name + ")-[:Lives_in]->(" + num + ")")
```

Lives_inRelationship("Chandler","19")
'''the exception'''
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Invalid input '19': expected "(", "allShortestPaths" or "shortestPath" (line 1, column 45 (offset: 44))
"MATCH (Chandler:person {name:'Chandler'}), (19:Apartment {number:'19'})MERGE (Chandler)-[:Lives_in]->(19)"
^}

Answer (score 0):

Probably the ‘19’ identifier. try to insert an underscore. So ‘_19’ in the MATCH and the MERGE for the rel.

Answer (score 0):

All the label names, relationship names, alias names should not start with number. In your query, we see for Apartment label alias name given as 19. So, it is giving error. Please see below reference for information on naming conventions

https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/naming/